# HTML, display label if drop down has just one value

Tags: html, jquery, html-select, smarty

I am generating the drop down dynamically by script (Smarty).

If the drop down has just one option value, is it possible to display it as a label.

This will display a drop down with 3 values.

```
<select>
    <option> 1 </option>
    <option> 2 </option>
    <option> 3 </option>
</select>
```

If it shows just one value then display it as label, is it possible with pure HTML or Jquery or combination of both? I could use smarty to check for the values and throw different different html, but that would make my code long as I have many drop downs.

```
<select>
    <option> 1 </option>
</select>
```

Any simple logic, which I might be missing?

**UPDATE (RESOLVED)**

Thank for all the stackoverflow'ers  who helped.
I used the code given by @ahren which worked as required.

However I have expanded the code to copy the attributes of one tag to another, in case if someone is looking for

```
// To replace a <select>, with <label> tag if it has just one value
$('select').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('option').length === 1){

        // Copy all attributes from a given tag and save it in a variable.
        var attributes_from = $(this).prop("attributes");
        var attributes_to = '';
        $.each(attributes_from, function() {
            attributes_to += ' '+this.name+'="'+this.value+'"';
        });

        // If select then copy its value from option.
        attributes_to += ' value="'+$(this).find('option').attr('value')+'"';

        // Replace the <tag>
        $(this).replaceWith(function(){
            return $('<label '+attributes_to+' />').html($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('select').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('option').length === 1){
    $(this).replaceWith(function(){
       return $('<label />').html($(this).text());
    });
  }
});
```

After you've generated your dropdowns, you can just run this snippet to check each of the `select` elements.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kqunE/

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a small and smart function, have been scratching my head for a day regarding this 7 line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd iterate over each of the `<select>` elements, checking the number of options they have, and make the required DOM changes accordingly:

```
$('select').each(function(index, select) {
    var numOptions = $('option', this).length;
    if(numOptions === 1) {
        // replace the select element here - something like the below
        var label = $('<label>').html(this.value);
        $(this).after(label).hide();
    }
});
```

I opted to hide, rather than replace, the `<select>` element so you still get the value sent back as part of the form. If that's not required then you can remove the element entirely using `.remove()` in place of `.hide()`.

Comment: Hi, @Anthony thanks for your help as well, haven't tested your code, but it seems to follow same logical steps as code of (at)ahren and it should work.